# ¿Cómo modificar un registro BD Realm en Android?

Tags: java, android, realm

No encuentro la forma para hacer un update usando [Realm en Java de Android](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/).

Agregar datos y eliminar ningún problema, solo tengo problemas en modificar datos ya existentes, siempre me salta que la `primary key` ya existe y no se puede sobrescribir, pero es que es obvio le asigno el mismo id para así solapar los cambios.

**Mi objeto RealmInfoDB** Es una tabla realm

```
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

public class RealmInfoDB extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    private long lastUpdate;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(long lastUpdate) {
        if (lastUpdate == 0) lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

}
```

Para agregar un nuevo registro

```
realm.beginTransaction();
    RealmInfoDB infoDB =  realm.createObject(RealmInfoDB.class);
    infoDB.setId(0);
    infoDB.setLastUpdate(0);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Para modificar uso lo mismo y es cuando me salta el error

```
realm.beginTransaction();
    RealmInfoDB infoDB =  realm.createObject(RealmInfoDB.class);
    infoDB.setId(0);
    infoDB.setLastUpdate(0);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

**Error**

> io.realm.exceptions.RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already
>   exists: 0

**Log error entero**

```
06-09 00:24:01.909 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: realm.test.app.testrealm, PID: 1177
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{realm.test.app.testrealm/realm.test.app.testrealm.MainActivity}: io.realm.exceptions.RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists: 0
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4032)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
    Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists: 0
       at io.realm.internal.Table.throwDuplicatePrimaryKeyException(Table.java:684)
       at io.realm.internal.Table.addEmptyRow(Table.java:371)
       at io.realm.Realm.createObject(Realm.java:696)
       at realm.test.app.testrealm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4032) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Webserveis id esta definida como llave primaria, actualizar este campo no sería posible:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
    RealmInfoDB infoDB =  realm.createObject(RealmInfoDB.class);
    infoDB.setId(0);
    infoDB.setLastUpdate(0);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

prueba esta forma donde únicamente se actualizaría `lastUpdate` :

```
    RealmInfoDB myObj;
    RealmInfoDB updateObj = realm.where(RealmInfoDB.class)
                            .equalTo("0", myObj.getId()).findFirst();
realm.beginTransaction();     
 updateObj.setLastUpdate(myObj.getLastUpdate());
```

Comment: perfecto me ha servido, el error que realizaba era que el objeto partia de nada, es decir no se extendia del registro que queria modificar

Answer (score 1):

El error es que estás generando 2 inserciones con el mismo ID..
deberías hacer esto

```
realm.beginTransaction();
RealmInfoDB infoDB =  realm.createObject(RealmInfoDB.class);
infoDB.setId(0);
infoDB.setLastUpdate(0);
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(infoDB );//nada más te faltó agregar esto, insertar o actualizar registro
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Por otro lado observo que en el primer query le faltaría agregar `copyToRealm(infoDB);`

```
realm.beginTransaction();
RealmInfoDB infoDB =  realm.createObject(RealmInfoDB.class);
infoDB.setId(0);
infoDB.setLastUpdate(0);
realm.copyToRealm(infoDB); //instrucción para asegurar inserción
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Bueno aquí debió aparecer un error si no le habías agregado `copyToRealm`, no sé xq no te salió un error, pero bueno..